# Hide application files from user Visual C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

After installing my application on a clients machine, How can I securely hide files used by my program from the user? Such as pdf's and video files. I am using C# and windows forms in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Lookup Embedded Resources in Assemblies.

Comment: If there is a lot of content and you don't want to bloat your assemblies out with embvedded resources, you will need to look in to encryption. [C# Encryption](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010/en-gb)

Comment: there is a lot of files but if I encrypt them I have to decrypt a file and store it on disk every time I need to open the file  right? then the user can access it while my program is using it.

Comment: What you ask is in most cases not done. I can't recall any piece of software that goes to extreme length to hide installed media files. They don't want anyone to debug the code, but that's all. So, the question is why do you want this?

Comment: All the program basically does is shows users the files. If they can see the files without the program then the program is useless. If I sell the files without a program, users can just share them for free without having to buy them

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using a ZIP `Package` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage(v=vs.110).aspx)).
You can store your files in the package with `CompressionOption.SuperFast` or even `CompressionOption.NotCompressed` to maximize performance. All your files will be located in that package, and you will be able to modify and save them back.
Unfortunately, there is no option to encrypt nor password protect the package, and the user will be able to "open" your package in a ZIP tool (or even via Explorer), if he or she knows the file name and does understand that file extension doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt commented, Embedded Resources is a way. Just remember that if you're currently navigating to your files (e.g. c:\MyApp\MyFile.pdf), you will not be able to do that anymore if you change these files to Embedded Resources.

Have a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file).

You may also consider creating a Resource file (.resx) and adding your pdf's and videos into the resource file.

Comment: there is a lot of files but if I encrypt them I have to decrypt a file and store it on disk every time I need to open the file right? then the user can access it while my program is using it

Comment: Yes that's right,  users could still access encrypted file via Explorer, but wouldn't be able to open the files directly. With Embedded Resources or using a Resource file, the files are compiled into the dll / exe, so the user cannot get hold of them directly.
The solution @dymanoid proposes is a good one to consider as well. But it still means users can access the zipped file directly. If you don't mind that, then it's probably a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it by converting all files to shock wave flash files and encrypting them. Then I could decrypt the files into a memory stream and display straight into a flash player.